# Upload files (csv) from R to Github

Tags: r, github

This is probably a long shot, but is it possible to upload a file from R to a Github repo *within* the R script? Similar to how you `write_csv()` if you wanted to save a dataframe locally.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a dataframe, then you can write the dataframe as a plain text file in the R script. You can do this whether you are using a local directory or a Github repository.

```
# Using a local directory
library(git2rdata)

root <- "~/myproject" 
write_vc(my_data, file = "rel_path/filename", root = root)
read_vc(file = "rel_path/filename", root = root)
root <- git2r::repository("~/my_git_repo") # git repository

# Using a git repository
library(git2rdata)

repo <- repository("~/my_git_repo")
pull(repo)
write_vc(my_data, file = "rel_path/filename", root = repo, stage = TRUE)
commit(repo, "My message")
push(repo)
read_vc(file = "rel_path/filename", root = repo)
```

You can read more about `git2rdata` on [Github](https://github.com/ropensci/git2rdata).

Comment: This looks great. I had not heard of this package and it didn't show up in my searches. Thank you!